# How to fetch JSON in Mustache template?

Tags: arrays, json, mustache

I want to fetch the given JSON data to a mustache template.

```
{
  "1": {
    "feedbackid": "1",
    "name": "Harshad",
    "email": "harshadbindra@gmail.com",
    "message": "asdasdf"
  },
  "2": {
    "feedbackid": "2",
    "name": "Tom",
    "email": "tom@gmail.com",
    "message": "test"
  },
  "3": {
    "feedbackid": "3",
    "name": "Harshad",
    "email": "harshadbindra@gmail.com",
    "message": "asdfasdfas"
  }
}
```

All this data is contained in a variable $data. So, how can you access it within the `.mustache` file?

Thanks in advance.